# DOT (Graph). Serialize with vertex and edge positions

Tags: c

There is a file with nodes and parents (DOT). How can you serialize it in JSON or something else that would also be the coordinates of vertices (XY), edges and everything else? What would be possible to use third-party tools (completely different in purpose) to display the graph.

DOT:

```
digraph G {

    subgraph cluster_0 {
        style=filled;
        color=lightgrey;
        node [style=filled,color=white];
        a0 -> a1 -> a2 -> a3;
        label = "process #1";
    }

    subgraph cluster_1 {
        node [style=filled];
        b0 -> b1 -> b2 -> b3;
        label = "process #2";
        color=blue
    }
    start -> a0;
    start -> b0;
    a1 -> b3;
    b2 -> a3;
    a3 -> a0;
    a3 -> end;
    b3 -> end;

    start [shape=Mdiamond];
    end [shape=Msquare];
}
```

Looking for data like this (pseudocode):

```
{
    Node {
        xCoordinate;
        yCoordinate;
        parents[];
        childs[]
    },
    Edge {
        bezierCurve,
        other...
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us input DOT file and expected JSON

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55051175/edit) your question and put example input (a dot file) and expected output (a json file) into question

Comment: Edited. The most important thing is to get node coordinates and edge data. And colors and other parameters are not needed.